# Clickable HTML element that closes Highcharts tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I need to implement a tooltip with a close icon which will close the tooltip if tapped. The icon is and HTML element rendered using formatter function, jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e56KT/

```
<div>Clickable close</div>
```

is a node which will be replaced with an icon).

Is there way to implement it?

Comment: Do you want to click to bring up the tooltip, and then click to close it again, or do you want the normal automatic tooltip to appear, but not go away until clicked ? If it doesn't go away automatically, what will happen if you hover over another point. Will two tooltips appear ?

Comment: Our platform is iPad we need to click a point, get a tooltip and then close it if a particular HTML node is clicked in that tooltip. If other point is clicked then another tooltip has to pop up and current has to disappear. If 'Close' button is clicked in the tooltip i'd like to hide tooltip and stop event propagation to prevent another tooltip being opened (just in case click happened above other clickable area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide tooltip using `chart.tooltip.hide()`, so for example: http://jsfiddle.net/e56KT/1/

Comment: Thanks, Pawel, which event should I listen and stop propagation if its target is my desired element to prevent another tooltip? I've tried chart's onclick but by the time it is handled another tooltip is already opened.

Comment: I think you can achieve that in a different way. Add flag if tooltip should be shown or not. Then in `point.events.mouseover` add checking if  tooltip should be displayed or not. (To display tooltip use `this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this.point);`)